# Adding text below/above a switch button in Android menu icon

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I am trying to add a text below/above this `switch` item that is in my `Toolbar` to indicate functionality of the switch. I was wondering if there is a layout tag I could use to add a text below/above the button. Or is there some other method I have to use.

menu_main.xml

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:title="@string/app_name"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Switch"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_edit"
        app:showAsAction="always" android:visible="true"/>
```

Currently it looks like this:

[image: Toolbar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom menu layout that has a `Switch` and a `TextView` of its description

**layout/menu_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/menuRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/menu_switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/switch_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OFF"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then utilize the `app:actionLayout` attribute of the menu item to attach the custom menu

**menu/my_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/switchItem"
        android:title="switch"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_layout"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

And you can detect the switch click callbacks and change the description accordingly as below:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.switchItem);
        LinearLayout root = item.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.menuRoot);
        SwitchCompat menuSwitch = root.findViewById(R.id.menu_switch);
        TextView switchText = root.findViewById(R.id.switch_text);
        menuSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                switchText.setText(isChecked? "ON" : "OFF");
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

A preview

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary.
The user can understand.
Developers often don't put text into tools, it's the placement of icons.
You can learn more about the menu at: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus?hl=vi

Comment: I was planning to add a few more switches so having text would be helpful in my own opinion